# Disable an IBAction-linked button

Tags: objective-c, button, ibaction

I made a button using Interface Builder and linked it to an action. I'd like to disable the *hit* button on the `if` statement below.

```
- (IBAction)hit:(id)sender {
    Application *app = [[Application alloc] init];
    int nc = [app dealCard];
    [userOne setIntValue:tu];
    [userTwo setIntValue:nc];
    tu += nc;
    [totalUser setIntValue:tu];
    BOOL bust = [app checkBust:tu];
    if (bust == YES) {
        [console setIntValue:1];
        //Disable button here.
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It turns out I was using an `NSButton` instead of a `UIButton` so I changed the declaration to: `NSButton *theButton = (NSButton *)sender;`.

Then I replaced `theButton.enabled = NO;` to `[theButton setEnabled = NO];`.

So here's my finished code:

```
- (IBAction)hit:(id)sender {
    Application *app = [[Application alloc] init];
    NSButton *theButton = (NSButton *)sender;
    int nc = [app dealCard];
    [userOne setIntValue:tu];
    [userTwo setIntValue:nc];
    tu += nc;
    [totalUser setIntValue:tu];
    BOOL bust = [app checkBust:tu];
    if (bust == YES) {
        [console setIntValue:1];
        [theButton setEnabled = NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIButton` is a subclass of `UIResponder` which has an `enabled` property. Set this to `NO` to disable the action from the button. E.g.

```
UIButton *theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
theButton.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I the error: "UIButton undeclared" when I enter the code. Should I declare it in the _.h_ file? If so, how?

Comment: @Simon: Try it now. I'm just casting the sender as an instance of `UIButton`. If you're using something other than a `UIButton`, then remove the first line and just do `sender.enabled = NO;`

Comment: I tried the second option and I got the error: "Request for member 'enabled' in something not a structure or union." Thank you for your patience.

Comment: This is probably because you have no cast `sender` correctly, so the compiler doesn't think that it has the property `enabled`. Make sure you've set up the connections in the IB correctly, while you're at it.

Comment: Turns out that I had created an `NSButton` instead of a `UIButton` I changed the syntax and replaced `theButton.enabled = NO;` to `[theButton setEnabled = NO];`. Thanks for your help!